# Making the Dock immutable

Tags: dock, parental-controls

A relative who has difficulty with mouse control keeps inadvertently removing items from his Dock.  I enabled Parental Controls to prevent him from doing so, but Parental Controls has a [bug that prevents access to secure websites](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72990/unable-to-view-secure-web-pages-from-one-particular-user-account), including any banking site.

How do I lock the Dock so that it cannot be modified, without making use of Parental Controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3870488?start=0&tstart=0) on Apple Support Communities:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock contents-immutable -bool true; killall Dock
```